# How can I check if times overlap based on 2 criteria?

Tags: r

I have a data frame df with the following columns:

```
ID <- c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3)
value <- c("A","B","C","A","C","B", "C")
start_time <- c("2017-12-21 14:04:15", "2017-12-21 14:13:04", "2017-12-21 14:04:40", "2017-12-08 13:18:28", "2017-12-08 13:19:03", "2017-12-06 11:33:31", "2017-12-06 11:32:37")
end_time <- c("2017-12-21 14:06:37","2017-12-21 14:54:0","2017-12-21 14:20:38","2017-12-08 13:18:35","2017-12-08 13:23:42","2017-12-06 11:38:27","2017-12-06 11:38:27")
```

Expected outcome:

I want to add a column with a Y or N values if start and end times overlap for rows with the same ID and for values of (A or B) and C. Please note that there are rows which may not have all 3 values.

So finally the data frame should look like this:

```
ID   Value     start_time                 end_time                Overlap
1    A         2017-12-21 14:04:15        2017-12-21 14:06:37     Y
1    B         2017-12-21 14:13:04        2017-12-21 14:54:0      Y
1    C         2017-12-21 14:04:40        2017-12-21 14:20:38     Y
2    A         2017-12-08 13:18:28        2017-12-08 13:18:35     N
2    C         2017-12-08 13:19:03        2017-12-08 13:23:42     N
3    B         2017-12-06 11:33:31        2017-12-06 11:38:27     Y
3    C         2017-12-06 11:32:37        2017-12-06 11:38:27     Y
4    A         2017-11-01 08:00:00        2017-11-01 08:00:05     N
4    B         2017-11-01 08:00:04        2017-11-01 08:00:10     N
4    C         2017-11-01 08:00:11        2017-11-01 08:00:15     N
5    A         2017-11-01 08:01:25        2017-11-01 08:01:40     N
5    A         2017-11-01 08:01:42        2017-11-01 08:02:05     N
5    C         2017-11-01 08:02:06        2017-11-01 08:02:15     N
```

How can this can be done?

Comment: Perhaps `df %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(Overlap = any(lead(start_time) < end_time))`

Comment: The second condition is not clear to me.  Could you describe more and also include rows where it is not A, B, or C

Comment: @akrun rows with IDs 2 and 3 describe the second condition. Rows with ID 2 have A and C but not B. Rows with ID 3 have B and C but not A. Bottomline all IDs will have either A and/or B AND C. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(dplyr)

df$start_time <- as.POSIXct(df$start_time, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
df$end_time <- as.POSIXct(df$end_time, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  arrange(ID, value) %>%
  mutate(overlap = ifelse((start_time >= lag(start_time) & start_time <= lag(end_time)) | 
                            (end_time >= lag(start_time) & end_time <= lag(end_time)) |
                            (start_time >= lag(start_time, 2) & start_time <= lag(end_time, 2) & !is.na(lag(start_time, 2))) |
                            (end_time >= lag(start_time, 2) & end_time <= lag(end_time, 2) & !is.na(lag(start_time, 2))), "Y", "N")) %>%
  mutate(overlap = ifelse(value=='C', overlap, NA)) %>%
  fill(overlap, .direction = "up") %>%
  data.frame()
```

Output is:

```
  ID value          start_time            end_time overlap
1  1     A 2017-12-21 14:04:15 2017-12-21 14:06:37       Y
2  1     B 2017-12-21 14:00:04 2017-12-21 14:00:00       Y
3  1     C 2017-12-21 14:04:40 2017-12-21 14:20:38       Y
4  2     A 2017-12-08 13:18:28 2017-12-08 13:18:35       N
5  2     C 2017-12-08 13:19:03 2017-12-08 13:23:42       N
6  3     B 2017-12-06 11:33:31 2017-12-06 11:38:27       Y
7  3     C 2017-12-06 11:32:37 2017-12-06 11:38:27       Y
```

Sample data:

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3), value = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C"), class = "factor"), 
    start_time = structure(c(6L, 5L, 7L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("2017-12-06 11:32:37", 
    "2017-12-06 11:33:31", "2017-12-08 13:18:28", "2017-12-08 13:19:03", 
    "2017-12-21 14:00:04", "2017-12-21 14:04:15", "2017-12-21 14:04:40"
    ), class = "factor"), end_time = structure(c(5L, 4L, 6L, 
    2L, 3L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("2017-12-06 11:38:27", "2017-12-08 13:18:35", 
    "2017-12-08 13:23:42", "2017-12-21 14:00:0", "2017-12-21 14:06:37", 
    "2017-12-21 14:20:38"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("ID", 
"value", "start_time", "end_time"), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Error in `[[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, col, value = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,  : 
  replacement has 7 rows, data has 8044

Comment: @aditya can you update your original question with a sample data to reproduce this error?

Comment: I have added two more groups of IDs. Hopefully this helps. Could the error mean that I am trying to run the code on only 7 rows instead of 8044 which are the total observations in my dataset?

Comment: I really don't think so but try `df <- na.omit(df)` before running my code. BTW - my answer runs pretty clean on your new dataset as well.